# Genymotion black screen

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, genymotion

I have installed genymotion 2.8.1 on ubuntu 16.04 along side virtual box 5.1. When I try to run the emulator, it gives a black screen. If I run it from virtual box, [following messages come up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxrYd.png).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem as follows.

Uninstall VirtualBox via the command line (`sudo apt-get remove virtualbox` and `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-guest-utils`) and reinstall VirtualBox with the `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` command.

Voilà, Genymotion started working normally.
I also noticed that VirtualBox was installed with a different icon.